# Получить нечётное значение

Tags: php

```
for ($i=0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    echo $i;
}
```

Выводит **1,2,3,4,5,6**. А как вывести только чётные **2,4,6**?

Comment: Надеюсь, следующим вопросом не будет "А как вывести только нечётные?"?

Comment: Вопрос, получить нечетные и тут-же получить четные, это вообще как? Вы уж определитесь, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Либо внедрить проверку четности внутрь цикла:

```
if ($i%2 == 0) echo $i;
```

либо сделать цикл с шагом 2

```
for($i=0; $i<=6; $i+=2){
```

очевидно, второе предпочтитетельнее.